# Take selected item from listbox in form2 and put it to Form1 to TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, listbox

I'm trying take take selectedItem from **ListBox** in **Form2** and put it to **TextBox** in **Form1**, but my error is

---

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

---

I know what is null object, i know what is it doing and when does it doing, but i can't find my mistake.

My code in **Form2**, where I have my **ListBox**

```
private Form1 mainForm = null;
    public Form2(Form1 callingFrom)
    {
        mainForm = callingFrom as Form1;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.mainForm.udaje = bankovniUctyList.GetItemText(bankovniUctyList.SelectedItem);
        this.Close();
    }
```

My code in **Form1**, where I have my **TextBox**

```
 public string udaje
    {
        get { return predmetBanka.Text; }
        set { predmetBanka.Text = value; bankaTextBox.Text = predmetBanka.Text; }
    }
```

Debugger says, that problem is here

```
this.mainForm.udaje = bankovniUctyList.GetItemText(bankovniUctyList.SelectedItem);
```

I have no idea, why is it null.

Comment: Is something actually selected in the `ListBox` when you click OK?

Comment: Also, which object is null on that line?

Comment: @MikeH I dont know which object is null, but it says this: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in iTextSharp.exe. But yes, i have actually selected item

Comment: When you have this exception: Hover over each of the items on that line (it will show you the current value of that item).  One of those items will be null.

Comment: @MikeH Yes, i found it. The error is throwing "udaje"

Comment: Ok, the error is likely in the setter of `udaje`.  Set a break point there and find out what is null.  BTW, this would probably be a useful read for you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: What does your code look like in Form1, where you construct Form2?  Are you sending "this" (which is the pointer to Form1) into your constructor for Form2 or are you sending in null or something else?

Comment: @MikeH But, i have used same approach in Form3 to Form2. Everything is good. In Form3 i take string text input and put it into Form2 as ListBox item. And then i take ListBox item, which was taken from Form3 as text and there is problem. Same aprroach used in Form3 and Form2 doesnt work in Form2 and Form1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just needed to modify from this

```
Form2 form = new Form2();
```

To this

```
Form2 form = new Form2(this);
```